# difference in file size after doing ftp it to remote machine

Tags: java, file, ftp

I created the backup of file at my machine . Its in the form name.tar.gz
After that i need to transfet it to remote machine , so i created the input stream as

```
InputStream stream = files[0].endsWith(FILE_EXT) ? 
                        new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(toUpload)) : 
                            new FileInputStream(toUpload);
```

after transfering the file to remote machine using command `ftp.put(stream, fileName)`;

my file size increase from 92Mb to 1Gb. Why it is so? Whole code is in java.
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us which FTP library you are using?

Comment: Probably an issue with text mode vs. binary mode?

Comment: com.enterprisedt.net.ftp libraries we are using

Comment: please show the code where you are streaming

Comment: What actually is happening is that , after creating the abc.tar.gz file at my machine we are creating GZIPInputStream and then ftping that file, i doubt whether its a right way to do it or not??